# Javascript Form Validation with Spring WebFlow

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-webflow

I am trying to find a way to do some Javascript Form Validation with Spring WebFlow.

I have the following code in my JSP

```
<INPUT tabIndex="46" value="Submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" onClick="return dontSubmit();">
```

that runs a JavaScript function and returns false is the form does not pass validation but my page is still getting submitted to the server.  I don't want it submitted if I found a validation error

I also tried:

```
<INPUT tabIndex="46" value="Submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" onsubmit="return dontSubmit();"
```

and again if find a error the form still gets submitted. please I tried:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="visit" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" onsubmit="dontSubmit()">
```

and again the form gets submitted with and without errors.....  please help below you will find the funcation

```
function dontSubmit()
{
    alert("DONT SUBMITTED TO SERVER");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: change onClick to onSubmit and check I think it should work then.also check out this URL [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: okay why dont you check this post out [onsubmitUsingJQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_submit)

Comment: @Jonathan did you try this method?

Comment: I had the same problem. I think your issue is not because of spring-webflow. Most probably somewhere in your JS function, you had an error which stops the JS to reach the "return false".

Answer (score 0):

Place the `onsubmit` on the FORM tag:

```
<FORM action="..." onsubmit="return checkrequired();" method="POST">
   <INPUT tabIndex="46" value="Submit" type="submit" name="_eventId_submit" >
```

See [JavaScript Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp).

Comment: Can you post your `checkrequired()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Generally a form validation is done using something like the following:

```
<form action="server.action" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate(this);">
<input .../>

<input type="submit" name="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

where `this` in the `validate` function is a reference to the form

Comment: yes but its not working I posted my code if I found a error and return false it still gets posted

Comment: Do you see the alert when you post the form?